# Plotting some displays from a weather URL

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, matplotlib

I've got some code that plots some displays from a weather URL and locations in a CSV file. I'd like to see if anyone can make the code more efficient, the code runs fine without any errors and I'm aware you won't be able to test it, but if anyone could take a look at making a class function or breaking up the functions so they can be handled better I'd appreciate it. This is the first piece of code I've ever written so I'm sorry about how it looks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import UKMap
import csv
import requests
import bs4
import datetime as dt

def windy (open_file, close_file):
    with open(open_file, 'r') as csvfile, open(close_file, 'w') as csvoutput:
        towns_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')    # csv reader
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n') # csv writer
        for rows in towns_csv:
            x = float(rows[2])                              # gets x axis
            y = float(rows[1])                              # gets y axis
            url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?{0};{1}" # start of url string
            lat = "lat={}".format(y)                        # creates the latititue part of the url string
            lon = "lon={}".format(x)                        # creates the longitude part of the url string
            text = url.format(lat, lon)                     # combines the strings together to create a new url
            response = requests.get(text).text              # get the url into text format                           
            winds= bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")       
        # uses BeautifulSoup to make an xml file
            wind_all = winds.find_all("windSpeed")          # finds the "windSpeed" element
            speeds = wind_all[0].get("mps")                  # finds the first "mps" attribute
            wind_dir = winds.find_all("windDirection")      # finds the "windDirection" element
            wind_dirs = wind_dir[0].get("deg")              # finds the "deg" attribute
            rows.append(speeds)                              # append speed value
            rows.append(wind_dirs)                          # append wind value
            writer.writerow(rows)

def speed(file):
    with open(file) as latloncsv:
        towns_csv = csv.reader(latloncsv, dialect='excel')
        datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
        for rows in towns_csv:
            x = float(rows[2]) # x co-ordinates
            y = float(rows[1]) # y co-ordinates
            u = float(rows[3]) # wind speed
            v = float(rows[4]) # wind direction
        # plots a scatter of the x and y co-ordinates using the wind direction 
        #to orientate and the speed to adjust the colour
            plt.scatter(x, y, marker =(3,0,v), c=u, vmin=0, vmax =10, 
                cmap='jet', s=50, edgecolors='none')
        cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink = .5) # print colourbar
        cbar.set_label('Wind Speed (mps)') # labels the colourbar
        UKMap.UKMap() # prints basemap 
        plt.savefig('Speed_Direction' + datestring + '.jpg')# save plot name           
        plt.show()

def get_data(open_file, save_file): 
    with open(open_file, 'r') as csvfile, open(save_file, 'w') as csvoutput:
        towns_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')    # csv reader
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n') # csv writer
        for rows in towns_csv:
            x = float(rows[2])                              # gets x axis
            y = float(rows[1])                              # gets y axis
            url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?{0};{1}" # start of url string
            lat = "lat={}".format(y)                        # creates the latititue part of the url string
            lon = "lon={}".format(x)                        # creates the longitude part of the url string
            text = url.format(lat, lon)                     # combines the strings together to create a new url
            response = requests.get(text).text              # get the url into text format                           
            temps= bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")       
        # uses BeautifulSoup to make an xml file
            temp_all = temps.find_all("precipitation")          # finds the "windSpeed" element
            windy = temp_all[0].get("value")                  # finds the first "mps" attribute
            rows.append(windy)                              # append speed value                          # append wind value
            writer.writerow(rows)  
            return(rows)

def rainfall():                 
    with open('rain1.csv') as latloncsv:
        towns_csv = csv.reader(latloncsv, dialect='excel')
        datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    for rows in towns_csv:
        x = float(rows[2]) # x co-ordinates
        y = float(rows[1]) # y co-ordinates
        u = float(rows[3]) # rainfal
        volume = (u)**3
        plt.scatter(x, y, c=u, marker ='*', vmin=0, vmax =12, cmap='cool_r', 
                    s=volume, facecolor='none', edgecolors='none')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink = .5) # print colourbar
    cbar.set_label('Precipitation (mm)') # labels the colourbar
    UKMap.UKMap() # prints basemap
    plt.savefig('Rainfall' + datestring + '.jpg')# save plot name            
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Imports

[From documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23):

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - standard library imports
> - related third party imports
> - local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

So, your imports will look like this:

```
import bs4
import csv
import datetime as dt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests

import UKMap
```

---

#### Styling

You don't need any space after a functions' name:

```
def windy (open_file, close_file)
         ^
         |____ not needed
```

More, you should have two newlines between functions:

```
...
import UKMap
# -- here, you should have two lines
def windy (open_file, close_file):
    ...
```

Around keywords/arguments, you should not have <kbd>space</kbd>s:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink = .5)
                          ^ ^
                          |_|
                           |______ not needed
```

Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters to improve readability. (I personally like to stick with PyCharm's convention of 120 characters length). The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

After each `,` you should have a <kbd>space</kbd>:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, marker =(3,0,v),
```

Should be:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, marker=(3, 0, v),
```

**Comments**

You have **way** too many comments. Inline comments are unnecessary and in fact distracting if they state the obvious. Rather than commenting each line of your code, you might want to document your functions by adding some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) and in addition, you might try to give your variables better names.

More, when you add a comment, don't use different styles:

```
# plots a scatter of the x ...
#to orientate and ...
UKMap.UKMap() # prints basemap
```

You should usually have two spaces after your last python statement and `#` and one space after `#`.

The right way to do it:

```
statement 1  # comment
```

---

#### Code improvements

When you're opening a file for reading, you can do:

```
with open(open_file) as csvfile ...
    ...
```

This will open the file in reading mode by default.

**DRY**(Don't repeat yourself)

Your code is really messy. I don't know how you're gonna use all of these functions. You didn't give us any hint.

You do repeat some lines of code multiple times, and this asks for a better structure of your code. Let's see how / what can we do.

What I'd personally do is move your reader / writer into two separate functions:

```
def csv_reader(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as towns_csv:
        return csv.reader(towns_csv, dialect='excel')


def csv_writer(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'w') as writer:
        return csv.writer(writer, lineterminator='\n')
```

Then, I'd get rid of some useless variables. First, your `windy` function might look like this:

```
def windy(csvfile_in, csvfile_out):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
    
    for rows in reader:
        url_text = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat={};lon={}".format(float(rows[1]),
                                                                                             float(rows[2]))

        response = requests.get(url_text).text
        winds = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")

        wind_all, wind_dir = winds.find_all("windSpeed"), winds.find_all("windDirection")
        speeds, wind_dirs = wind_all[0].get("mps"), wind_dir[0].get("deg")
        
        rows.append(speeds)
        rows.append(wind_dirs)
        
        writer.writerow(rows)
```

Then, doing the same as above for `speed` function, we get:

```
def speed(csvfile_in):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    for rows in reader:
        plt.scatter(float(rows[2]), 
                    float(rows[1]), 
                    marker=(3, 0, float(rows[4])), 
                    c=float(rows[3]), 
                    vmin=0, 
                    vmax=10, 
                    cmap='jet', 
                    s=50, 
                    edgecolors='none')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)
    cbar.set_label('Wind Speed (mps)')
    UKMap.UKMap()
    plt.savefig('Speed_Direction{}.jpg'.format(datestring))
    plt.show()
```

Moving forward to `get_data()`:

```
def get_data(csvfile_in, csvfile_out):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
    
    for rows in reader:
        url_text = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat={};lon={}".format(float(rows[1]),
                                                                                             float(rows[2]))
        response = requests.get(url_text).text
        temps = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")

        temp_all = temps.find_all("precipitation")
        windy = temp_all[0].get("value")
        
        rows.append(windy)
        writer.writerow(rows)

        return rows
```

And last but not least, `rainfall()`:

```
def rainfall(csvfile_in):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    for rows in reader:
        plt.scatter(float(rows[2]),
                    float(rows[1]),
                    c=float(rows[3]),
                    marker='*',
                    vmin=0,
                    vmax=12,
                    cmap='cool_r',
                    s=float(rows[3]) ** 3,
                    facecolor='none',
                    edgecolors='none')
        
    cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)  
    cbar.set_label('Precipitation (mm)')
    UKMap.UKMap()
    plt.savefig('Rainfall{}.jpg'.format(datestring))
    plt.show()
```

There're many ways of rewriting your code so that you don't have to repeat yourself, but as much as my time allowed, I came up with all of the above.

---

**The final code:**

```
import bs4
import csv
import datetime as dt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests

import UKMap


def csv_reader(csvfile_in):
    with open(csvfile_in) as towns_csv:
        return csv.reader(towns_csv, dialect='excel')


def csv_writer(csvfile_out):
    with open(csvfile_out, 'w') as writer:
        return csv.writer(writer, lineterminator='\n')


def windy(csvfile_in, csvfile_out):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)

    for rows in reader:
        url_text = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat={};lon={}".format(float(rows[1]),
                                                                                             float(rows[2]))

        response = requests.get(url_text).text
        winds = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")

        wind_all, wind_dir = winds.find_all("windSpeed"), winds.find_all("windDirection")
        speeds, wind_dirs = wind_all[0].get("mps"), wind_dir[0].get("deg")

        rows.append(speeds)
        rows.append(wind_dirs)

        writer.writerow(rows)


def speed(csvfile_in):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')

    for rows in reader:
        plt.scatter(float(rows[2]),
                    float(rows[1]),
                    marker=(3, 0, float(rows[4])),
                    c=float(rows[3]),
                    vmin=0,
                    vmax=10,
                    cmap='jet',
                    s=50,
                    edgecolors='none')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)
    cbar.set_label('Wind Speed (mps)')
    UKMap.UKMap()
    plt.savefig('Speed_Direction{}.jpg'.format(datestring))
    plt.show()


def get_data(csvfile_in, csvfile_out):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)

    for rows in reader:
        url_text = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat={};lon={}".format(float(rows[1]),
                                                                                             float(rows[2]))
        response = requests.get(url_text).text
        temps = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")

        temp_all = temps.find_all("precipitation")
        windy = temp_all[0].get("value")

        rows.append(windy)
        writer.writerow(rows)

        return rows


def rainfall(csvfile_in):
    """
    Your docstring here
    """
    reader = csv_reader(csvfile_in)
    datestring = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')

    for rows in reader:
        plt.scatter(float(rows[2]),
                    float(rows[1]),
                    c=float(rows[3]),
                    marker='*',
                    vmin=0,
                    vmax=12,
                    cmap='cool_r',
                    s=float(rows[3]) ** 3,
                    facecolor='none',
                    edgecolors='none')

    cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)
    cbar.set_label('Precipitation (mm)')
    UKMap.UKMap()
    plt.savefig('Rainfall{}.jpg'.format(datestring))
    plt.show()
```

---

*I know my code can be even more `DRY`ed but I'll let other reviewers handle what I've missed*

Comment: You should turn your `csv_reader` and `csv_writer` into context managers (see `@contextlib.contextmanager`) to avoid closing the files when you `return` the csv objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the effort you put it to helping me out.